# How to write mock implementation of async generic method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I'm writing unit tests for my service class but it calls an external WCF service, so need to mock this calls. This is the interface of wrapper of external WCF service calls.

```
internal interface IKoopServiceRequestHelper
{
Task<ServiceResponseDTO> CreateRequestAsync(ServiceRequestDTO serviceRequestDTO);

Task<TResponse> SendServiceMessagesAsync<TRequest, TResponse>(TRequest request, string messageCode)
    where TRequest : RequestDTO
    where TResponse : IResponseDTO;
}
```

To mock real implementation of this interface I wrote a stub class like below.

```
 class StubRequestHelper : IKoopServiceRequestHelper
{
    public async Task<ServiceResponseDTO> CreateRequestAsync(ServiceRequestDTO serviceRequestDTO)
    {
        return await Task.FromResult(new ServiceResponseDTO());
    }
}
```

But I cannot write a mock implementation of the second method named `SendServiceMessagesAsync` that has two generic type parameters.

Comment: `ServiceRequestDTO : RequestDTO` and `ServiceResponseDTO : IResponseDTO`? Why not using `moq`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `moq`. Assumptions are, in order to fullfill the constraints:

- `ServiceRequestDTO : RequestDTO`
- `ServiceResponseDTO : IResponseDTO`

Using `moq` should be fairly simple

```
var mock = new Mock<IKoopServiceRequestHelper>();
mock.Setup(m => m.CreateRequestAsync(It.IsAny<ServiceRequestDTO>()))
    .Returns(Task.FromResult(new ServiceResponseDTO()));
mock.Setup(m => m.SendServiceMessagesAsync<ServiceRequestDTO, ServiceResponseDTO>(It.IsAny<ServiceRequestDTO>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(Task.FromResult(new ServiceResponseDTO()));
```

Comment: I'm trying to use moq for this situation but ServiceRequestDTO and ServiceResponseDTO classes are not an implementation of TRequest and TResponse types of my generic method. They are types of external WCF service and I don't need to write generic version of that method. So I cannot write a mock like your answer using `SendServiceMessagesAsync<ServiceRequestDTO, ServiceResponseDTO>`

Comment: @johnny - Moq has supported `.ReturnsAsync()` for a while now, so you shouldn't need to use `Task.FromResult()` any more.

Comment: @sellotape, tnx for the suggestion. However, these methods are just extensions and will do the same thing...